# Typescript error when importing Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I will use `Intersection Observer API` to create an infinite scroll in my React app.

However, when importing Intersection Observer to the React component, I get an warning message `` Could not find a declaration file for module 'intersection-observer'. '/Users/rutakalytyte/Desktop/mano/reactprojects/react-movies-app/node_modules/intersection-observer/intersection-observer.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/intersection-observer` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'intersection-observer';` ``

This is the code

```
import{ useContext, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import '../../App.scss';
import 'intersection-observer';
import 'intersection-observer/intersection-observer.js'

const posterBaseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300";

const CatalogCards = () =>  { 
  const { setSelectedMovie, setIsMoviePageFirstTimeOpened } = useContext(MoviesContext);
  const loadingRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement|null>(null);
  
  const isBottomVisible = useIntersectionObserver(
    loadingRef,
    {
      threshold: 0 // to trigger event as soon as the element is in the viewport
    },
    false // to not remove the observer after intersected
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    //load next page when bottom is visible
    isBottomVisible && console.log("BOTTOM REACHED");
  }, [isBottomVisible]);

  return (
    <div >
      <div>Some components here</div>
      <div ref={loadingRef}>...</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CatalogCards;
```

These are the errors that I get:
[image: Error nr 1]
and
[image: Error nr 2]

This is my `package.json`:
[image: package.json file]

Also, running `npm i --save-dev @types/intersection-observer` command I get "code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET [https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fintersection-observer"](https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fintersection-observer%22)

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: try `npm i --save-dev @types/intersection-observer`, it may work

Comment: running this command I get "code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fintersection-observer"

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `index.d.ts` file to the root of your project folder and put this one line into it: `declare module "intersection-observer"`

Answer (score 0):

Add "dom" and "esnext" to your typescript config:

```
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "esnext"
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).